# Json Exception: Value connection of type String can't be converted to object

Tags: php, android, json, sqlite

this is my insert.php script

```
<?php

$name=$_POST['Name'] ?? ''  ;
$address=$_POST['Address'] ?? '' ;

include("db_config.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Firm`(`ID`,`NAME`,`ADDRESS`) VALUES ('','$name','$address')");    

$response = array();
 if($result){
    $response['success']=1;
    $response['message']="Record Inserted Successfully-".$result."--";
 }
else { 
    $response['success']=0;
    $response['message']="Insertion Failure-".$result."--";
 }

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

this is the response code

```
request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Utils.INSERT_FIRM, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
//                        Log.i("R","Response is "+s);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                            String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            Toast.makeText(Add_Firm.this,""+message+":"+ success,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Add_Firm.this, "Some Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("Error"," "+e.toString());
                        }
                    }
```

I am using php script to connect android with database
When I click the submit button in application
although insertion is happening at database but 
I keep getting this exception in android

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: Try to set the content type to `json` ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Comment: After going through this link , I added.                                       header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');                                         to the starting go php script...still my application throws JsonException: Value connection of type String cannot be converted to JsonObject..Any solution ?

Comment: What does this print: Log.i("R","Response is "+s);?

Comment: thanks.  The issue was that I had a statement echo "working";  because of which it was showing such error